# Downloading php_mysql.dll for php5

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed php5.3.2 and MySql on Ubuntu 10.4.

Now how do I add or download php_mysql.dll to add mysql support in php ?

I have visited [MySql Download page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/), but I don't know what to download.

Can someone point me in a right direction ?

I am not sure, if this question might fit in [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the package **php5-mysql** through apt-get.

Answer (score 5):

php_mysql.dll is for Windows only. Read this instalation [guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php) it may be helpfull.